# Splitting a string with multiple separators

Tags: python, split

I have a string which contains coordinates of chess pieces:

pieces = [Ka4Qb3Td7b4c4]

How can i split the string into a list, separated by the numbers?

Wanted output : ['Ka4', 'Qb3', 'Td7', 'b4', 'c4']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smells like homework, but easy enough..

```
import re
pieces = 'Ka4Qb3Td7b4c4'
m = re.compile('[A-Za-z]{1,2}\d+')
print m.findall(pieces)
```

Yields..

```
['Ka4', 'Qb3', 'Td7', 'b4', 'c4']
```

Comment: I'm not going to not post because I think it's homework.. Especially if the proposed solution in the question is poorly suited for the task. How can you expect people to learn if you don't help them?

Comment: Your answer is just code. You could *explain* how to split the string using regular expressions. That would be far more useful. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/147331 for more detailed reasoning.

Comment: It's always a tough call trying to figure out what depth one should go into when answering a question - generally when I see folks who're 500+ rep I tend to be a bit more brief letting the code talk for itself. If they're sub-100 I'll go into a bit more detail. I do appreciate the feedback though - food for thought.

Comment: The "tough call" is an excuse for "take too long, others answer first and get the points". So, it is a mater of being after the points, or wanting to write a great answer, that may not get so much upvotes because its late. Unfortunately stackexchange's voting system cant work around our own greed, we have to admit it.

Comment: Actually - the truth is, I play a game every day for about 15-30 minutes. I just try to, as fast as possible answer as many questions correctly as I can - kind of a 'lightning round'. Not really for the points, just for the fun of it. I don't know why anyone would 'game' the system anyway. Points can't be redeemed for anything, they have no intrinsic value. My co-workers don't use stack overflow and wouldn't be impressed with my score if they did. It's just a bit of fun. More challenging than playing a video game, less challenging than doing the work I procrastinate on for my 15-30 minutes..

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import re
mylist = []
pieces = "Ka4Qb3Td7b4c4"
for chunk in re.finditer("(.*?[0-9]{1})",pieces):
    mylist.append(chunk.group(1))
print mylist
```

You may need to adjust the regex if there are 2 digit seperators (I'm not a chess guy...)

For interest sake, I reworked it as the suggested list comprehension and agree it's much cleaner:

```
import re
pieces = "Ka4Qb3Td7b4c4"
mylist = [ chunk.group(0) for chunk in re.finditer(".*?\d+",pieces) ]
print mylist
```

Comment: this would look really nice with a list comprehension